# Flutter: My controller is showing in the remaining input fields

Tags: flutter, forms, validation, controller, texteditingcontroller

After extracting the method of my textformfield widget, I want to add controller to it using the TextEditingController,the issue is how to placed it in each fields but i have extracted it all to a method, but if I type anything it shows for all the input fields:

This is the signup part where I am trying to use the controller, but i kept it below

```
Container buildSignupSection() {
     return Container(
       margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
       child: Form(
         key: _signUpFormKey,
         child: Column(
           children: [
             buildTextField(
               "xpresschop",
               "Name",
               true,
               false,
               false,
             ),
             buildTextField(
               "example@gmail.com",
               "email",
               false,
               false,
               true,
             ),
             buildTextField(
               "......",
               "password",
               false,
               true,
               false,
             ),
             buildTextField(
               "......",
               "Confirm password",
               false,
               true,
               false,
             ),
           ],
         ),
       ),
     );
   }
```

How will i add it here

```
Widget buildTextField(String hintText, String labelText, bool isName,
      bool isPassword, bool isEmail) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
              controller: ,
            autocorrect: isAutoCorrect,
            obscureText: isPassword,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add different controller to each textfield, u can pass controller as parameter to buildTextField method

```
 var nameController = TextEditingController();
 ...
 buildTextField( "xpresschop", "Name", true, false, false, nameController)
 ...
```

then your widget would be:

```
Widget buildTextField(String hintText, String labelText, bool isName,
      bool isPassword, bool isEmail, TextEditingController myController) {
    return 
......
          TextFormField(
              controller:myController ,
....
```

Comment: I edited the code above. How will I add it to the widget below

Comment: You used nameController in the first code. Will I use the same code for all?

Comment: use another controller for other inputs like this:
var emailcontroller= TextEditingContoller(); 
and pass it to your method

Comment: Hello, I am having issue validating the fields one by one since i built a method for them into one, is there any way I can go about it?